# How to update row by row using python function in sqlite3?

Tags: python, database, sqlite

This question is duplicated I think, but I couldn't understand other answers...

1. Original table looks like this.

```
NAME    AGE SMOKE
John    25  None
Alice   23  None
Ken     26  None
```

2. I will update `SMOKE` column in these rows,
3. But **I need to use output of function which was coded in python `check_smoke()`.** If I input name to `check_smoke()`, then it returns `"Smoke"` or `"Not Smoke"`.
4. So final table would look like below:

```
NAME    AGE SMOKE
John    25  Smoke
Alice   23  Not Smoke
Ken     26  Not Smoke
```

I'm using sqlite3 and python3.
How can I do it? Thank you for help!

Comment: Easy way is to create a user defined function you can use in SQL statements. See the python sqlite3 module documentation for details and an example.

Comment: @Shawn Actually that function is external library and so complicated(connect to online and get data) that i cannot implement in SQL... Thank you for answering, but is there any other way?

Comment: If you can call it from python, you can wrap it in a SQL user defined function.

Comment: @Shawn Ah I see. I think I have to read documentation again. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use 1 cursor to select rows and another one to update them.

Assuming that the name of the table is smk (replace it by your actual name) and that `con` is an established connection to the database, you could do:

```
curs = con.cursor()
curs2 = con.cursor()
batch = 64            # size of a batch of records
curs.execute("SELECT DISTINCT name FROM smk")
while True:
    names = curs.fetchmany(batch)                             # extract a bunch of rows
    if len(names) == 0: break
    curs2.executemany('UPDATE smk SET smoke=? WHERE name=?',  #  and update them
              [(check_smoke(name[0]), name[0]) for name in names])
con.commit()
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you.

Comment: I'm also using this method. But it really feels like it has to be a better - more pythonic - way.